# Accessing link elements from a DivElement

Tags: javascript, dom

Basically, I'm trying to access a bunch of link-tags in order to have them exchange places, but however I try, I access the href attribute of the link instead of the actual HTML object of the link.

The solution is probably obvious, but currently I'm clueless...

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {

    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("div");
    var As = divs[0].getElementsByTagName("A");
  
    alert(As[0]) //Displays a url, not an html object


});
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <a href="">
  Hello
  </a>

 <a href="">
  Hello again
  </a>
  
  

</div>
```

Comment: You are obtaining the html object of the anchor tag and you can manipulate its attributes. Alert is giving the href attribute value, do `console.log(As[0])` and you'll see the html object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to access the tag and not the 'href' attribute, here is the explanation:

Try running this code:

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <div class="div">
               <a href="mylocation">
                 Hello
               </a>

               <a href="">
                 Hello again
               </a>
           </div>
       </body>
       <script>
          window.addEventListener("load", function () {
             var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("div");
             var As = divs[0].getElementsByTagName("a");

             alert(As[0]); //Displays a url, not an html object
             console.log(As[0]);
             As[0].innerHTML = "Some shit";
          });

       </script>
    </html>
```

*Console.log* displays the selected tag, but alert display the location.
Hence, you're accessing the element rightly.
Remember to check console when you open the file.

Anchor tags behave differently with 'Alert', check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: Thank you! Thought it was strange considering it worked previously with different elements, but this explains it.

Answer (score 0):

When you give an alert it shows the url (I do not know exactly why), but if you want to manipulate the element or get its contents (or anything you can do with an element) is possible, follow the example:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
    var As = divs[0].querySelectorAll("a");

    //example by manipulating
    As[0].style.color = "red"; //change the color (example)
    alert(As[0].innerHTML); //return "Hello"
    alert(typeof As[0]); //return "object"
    
    //but console.log return te element
    console.log(As[0]);
});
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <a href="">
    Hello
  </a>

  <a href="">
    Hello again
  </a>
</div>
```

**PS:** using `typeof` returns that the type is an object, but I really do not know why it shows a string referring to the href when `alert()`.

Answer (score 0):

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement):

> Inherits methods from its parent, HTMLElement, and implements those from HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils.

and

> HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils.toString():
>   Returns a USVString containing the whole URL. It is a synonym for URLUtils.href, though it can't be used to modify the value.

---

You are accessing the `href` value because you are converting `As[0]` to a string (implicitly because `alert()` converts everything you pass to it to a string).

If you want to see the element itself: Don't convert it to a string.

You could use `console.log` instead of `alert`. You could access a property of the element (such as `alert(As[0].innerHTML)`. Etc.